# Can I install Swift (OpenStack Storage Infrastructure) of OpenStack without installing Nova?

Tags: installation, cloud, openstack, openstack-swift

I'm trying to use OpenStack but I'm very confused.

I want to use [SWIFT](http://swift.openstack.org) (OpenStack Storage Infrastructure) to storage data. But I don't know how to install it. I was trying to follow this [tutorial](http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-compute/starter/content/OpenStack_Storage_Infrastructure_Swift_-d1e271.html) but it installs ALL SERVICES on a server (Server1)... I only need SWIFT.

Do I have to install Nova to get Swift?

Because in this tutorial, on Server1, at the hierarchical scheme, Swift belongs to Nova... But I thought it was apart.
If anyone know it and more, if anyone know a tutorial to install SWIFT on Ubuntu, please tell me. I was trying to install this component in my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop, but with all these doubts, I can't go ahead.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can perfectly install just a swift installation on one machine, independent of nova, glance or keystone (or any other openstack component). 
There is a [tutorial](http://swift.openstack.org/development_saio.html) on the openstack pages.

However, the tutorial is for older versions of Ubuntu: On Ubuntu 12.04 swift and it's dependencies (like the rest of openstack) are in the default repositories.
So no need to use git or the ppa, just use apt-get or aptitude to get the software:

```
sudo apt-get install swift swauth swift-account swift-container swift-object swift-proxy
```

This should get you started, modify configuration files as told in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenStack Object Storage Administration Manual](http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-object-storage/admin/content/) describes how to install Swift on its own.  See also the [Swift deployment guide](http://swift.openstack.org/deployment_guide.html).